# What is wrong with the following URL encoding?

Tags: http, encoding

```
https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?source=webclient&text=G%C5
```

produces the following error:

```
Invalid Unicode value in one or more parameters
```

btw, that is the Å character

Comment: Where exactly is this error produced?

Comment: Just a question: Should that not be xC5?

Comment: @Bart - No. This is [URL encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding). The `%` is correct.

Comment: @Oded Okay, didn't know that. Just wondered. Thanks.

Comment: When URL decoding `Å` in [this site](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/) I get: `%C3%85`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

twitter expects parameters to be encoded as utf-8.
So Å is Unicode U+00C5, and represented as utf-8 is C3 85
With url-escape this means that the query should be ...&text=G%C3%85

Since I don't know how you are building that query (programming language/environment), I can't really tell you how to do it right. Only that you should convert your string to utf-8 before escaping.